# Receive real JSON from frontend in Sails.js instead of bracket notation

Tags: javascript, sails.js

When I send a nested JSON to my Sails.js backend it parses it like this:

```
object: {
  '[prop1][prop2]': value
}
```

Instead of:

```
object: {
  prop1: {
    prop2: value
  }
}
```

I tried to configure the body parser like this:

```
// config/http.js
bodyParser: function () {
  var opts = {limit:'150mb', extended: true};
  var fn;

  fn = require('skipper');
  return fn(opts);
},
```

But it didn't help. What can I do?

---

[1. Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44831988/receive-real-json-from-frontend-in-sails-js-instead-of-bracket-notation#comment76659221_44831988)

**Request URL**

```
http://172.17.0.2:8080/api/user/tables/table/views/view/widgets/widget/get?tableIdentifier=1&widget%5Bidentifier%5D=1&widget%5Btype%5D%5Bchart%5D%5BselectedChart%5D=line&widget%5Btype%5D%5Bchart%5D%5BbeautifiedChartName%5D=Line+chart&widget%5Btype%5D%5Bchart%5D%5Bcolumns%5D%5BxAxis%5D=Date&widget%5Btype%5D%5Bchart%5D%5Bcolumns%5D%5ByAxis%5D=Float&datasetFilter%5BDate%5D%5BstartValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BDate%5D%5BendValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BDate%5D%5Btype%5D=date&datasetFilter%5BDate%5D%5Boption%5D=DD.MM.YYYY&datasetFilter%5BInteger%5D%5BstartValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BInteger%5D%5BendValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BInteger%5D%5Btype%5D=integer&datasetFilter%5BFloat%5D%5BstartValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BFloat%5D%5BendValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BFloat%5D%5Btype%5D=float&datasetFilter%5BFloat%5D%5Boption%5D=%2C&datasetFilter%5BComputed%5D%5BstartValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BComputed%5D%5BendValue%5D=&datasetFilter%5BComputed%5D%5Btype%5D=float&datasetFilter%5BComputed%5D%5Boption%5D=
```

**Query string parameters**

```
tableIdentifier:1
widget[identifier]:1
widget[type][chart][selectedChart]:line
widget[type][chart][beautifiedChartName]:Line chart
widget[type][chart][columns][xAxis]:Date
widget[type][chart][columns][yAxis]:Float
datasetFilter[Date][startValue]:
datasetFilter[Date][endValue]:
datasetFilter[Date][type]:date
datasetFilter[Date][option]:DD.MM.YYYY
datasetFilter[Integer][startValue]:
datasetFilter[Integer][endValue]:
datasetFilter[Integer][type]:integer
datasetFilter[Float][startValue]:
datasetFilter[Float][endValue]:
datasetFilter[Float][type]:float
datasetFilter[Float][option]:,
datasetFilter[Computed][startValue]:
datasetFilter[Computed][endValue]:
datasetFilter[Computed][type]:float
datasetFilter[Computed][option]:
```

2. Update

   `widget[identifier]:1
   widget[type][chart][selectedChart]:line
   widget[type][chart][beautifiedChartName]:Line chart
   widget[type][chart][columns][traces][0][xAxis][label]:Date
   widget[type][chart][columns][traces][0][xAxis][type]:date
   widget[type][chart][columns][traces][0][xAxis][option]:DD.MM.YYYY
   widget[type][chart][columns][traces][0][yAxis][label]:Integer
   widget[type][chart][columns][traces][0][yAxis][type]:integer
   widget[type][chart][columns][traces][0][yAxis][option]:`

Which results in at Sails.js:

```
{ identifier: '1',
  type: 
   { chart: 
      { selectedChart: 'line',
        beautifiedChartName: 'Line chart',
        columns: [Object] } } }
```

Everything is fine out of `columns` which got this format:

```
{ traces: 
   [ { '[xAxis][label]': 'Date',
       '[xAxis][type]': 'date',
       '[xAxis][option]': 'DD.MM.YYYY',
       '[yAxis][label]': 'Integer',
       '[yAxis][type]': 'integer',
       '[yAxis][option]': '' } ] }
```

Comment: Can you share your request as cURL command?

Comment: @Sangharsh, please see the 1. update.

Comment: As per my understanding, your request is parsed correctly, problem is with request parameters. Try this kind of request `http://172.17.0.2:8080/api/user/tables/table/views/view/widgets/widget/get?tableIdentifier=1&datasetFilter=%7B%22object%22%3A%7B%22prop1%22%3A%7B%22prop2%22%3A1%7D%7D%7D`  
which is encoded form of `http://172.17.0.2:8080/api/user/tables/table/views/view/widgets/widget/get?tableIdentifier=1&datasetFilter={"object":{"prop1":{"prop2":1}}}`

Comment: Not working. Actually, I posted the wrong example. And strangely parts of the object are parsed correctly. Only a sub object is wrong. Please see my 2. update.